# How to format cells in a QTableWidget

Tags: c++, qt, formatting, qtablewidget, qtablewidgetitem

my problem is not so simple for me, because I'm a niewbie in qt, so asking to the experts:  the problem, I populate dynamically a QTableWidget from a button on a toolbar, selecting data from a *.csv file.
All works fine but the formatting of the last column text rests on center-vertical position.
I had tryed to change styles or set directly on the code result: the app crash or nothing appens to the last column text.
(And if is possible how to change headers appearance).
Thank You in advance (& sorry for English mistakes).

```
void ToolBar::setDrawTable(QStringList sl)
{
    m_table->clear();
    QStringList slHeader = sl.at(0).split(';');
    sl.removeAt(0);
    m_table->setRowCount(sl.count());
    m_table->setColumnCount(slHeader.count());
    m_table->setHorizontalHeaderLabels(slHeader);
    for (int r= 0; r<sl.count(); r++){
        QStringList slRow = sl.at(r).split(';');
        for (int c = 0; c < slRow.count(); c++)
        {
            QTableWidgetItem *item =  new QTableWidgetItem(slRow.at(c));
            m_table->setItem(r, c, item);
            item->setTextAlignment(Qt::AlignHCenter | Qt::AlignVCenter);
        }
        slRow.clear();
    }
    m_table->setEditTriggers(QAbstractItemView::NoEditTriggers);
}
```

[image: Table result]

Comment: try changing `slRow.at(c)` to `slRow.at(c).trimmed()`

Comment: @eyllanesc thank you, it works!